# ListDensityPlot with discrete bins

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

We consider a table of the form

```
data = Flatten[Table[{i,j,f[i,j]},{i,1,ni},{j,1,nj}],1]
```

The function `f[i_,j_]` has been made so that `0 ≤ f[i,j] ≤ 1`. I can plot this map using

```
ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

However, the colors attributed to the values of `f[i,j]` are *continuous* and vary smoothly. I would like to have only a finite number of colors. For example : `0 ≤ f[i,j] ≤ 1/2  --> Red` and `1/2 ≤ f[i,j] ≤ 1  --> Blue` (Of course, my real bins will be different, but this is the idea.)

How could I proceed to make this plot so that only a finite number of colors are present on the plot with custom ranges ? I guess it has something to do with the `ColorFunction`, but I can't get the syntax correct...

Comment: @Kuba I took out the definitions in order to get a minimum working example as simple as possible. Your suggestion definitely works using `ColorFunction -> (If[# < .5, Red, Blue] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. However, I still don't understand this syntax. I would prefer to define a function `fcolor[value_]` which would give me the color associated to a value `f[i_,j_]`. What would then be the syntax for `ColorFunction -> ...` ?

Comment: Simple: `ColorFunction -> fcolor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `ColorFunction`, `ColorFunctionScaling`, and `InterpolationOrder`, e.g.:

```
ListDensityPlot[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[arg, 
   Which[0 <= arg < 1, Red, 1 <= arg < 2, Blue, 2 <= arg < 3, Green, True, Orange]]]
```

[image]

You can use similar constructs with `MatrixPlot` and `ArrayPlot`, which may be better fits for your needs.

Per your comment, if you want to externalize the color function, e.g.:

```
fcolor[arg_] := 
 Which[0 <= arg < 1, Red, 1 <= arg < 2, Blue, 2 <= arg < 3, Green, True, Orange]

ListDensityPlot[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ColorFunction -> fcolor]
```

Comment: Thank you. As I commented above to Kuba. Would you which syntax I could use to define the function `Function[arg, 
   Which[0 <= arg < 1, Red, 1 <= arg < 2, Blue, 2 <= arg < 3, Green, True, Orange]]` out of the `ListDensityPlot` ? With such a function `fcolor[value_]`, what would become the part `ColorFunction -> ..` ? (This is an additional question, your approach works perfectly.)

Comment: @jibe: see edit. Read docs re: details on the functionality of the various settings (I did the examples with what I *think* you had in mind). Also, use of `Interval` might be useful to you in defining ranges. Also, I'm a doofus - *xzczd* references the very question in which I show these methods - take a peek at it... and don't take it personally if this question is closed as a duplicate, helps keep things tight.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in my mind. My next step will now be to get a nice `PlotLegends` on the side, but I will first try on my own. ^^

Comment: Don't worry, I am not at all offended ! I am trying to use your answer to the duplicate, but the shorthened syntax using `#`, `@` and `&` is not obvious for a beginner like me... In any case, thanks again.