# How does a Pringle lose its curvature?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, differential-geometry

*Nom!*

As part of a bigger project, I've was writing some code to calculate the scalar curvature of surfaces of the form $z = f(x,y)$. This uses a general calculation of the scalar curvature to produce a function `ScalarCurvature` that calculates curvature in for surfaces with this specific form. However, I'm finding that some (but not all) of my test cases fail...

I suspect the issue comes from how I built a function from the output of the calculations, but the more standard way was failing to evaluate derivatives completely. I'm pretty sure the formula I obtain from the calculations is correct, it is just a matter of how it is put into a function.

**Behaviour**

What I'm finding is that for a sphere

```
ScalarCurvature[Sqrt[1 - (x^2 + y^2)], x, y] // FullSimplify
```

gives

```
2
```

as it should. But, for a Pringle

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image: pringle]

```
ScalarCurvature[x^2 - y^2, x, y]
```

yields

```
0
```

when it should, by my calculation, be

```
- 8 / (1 + 4x^2 + 4y^2)^2
```

**Code**

Here's the code, I'm pretty sure it is something to do with the bottom few lines

```
(* Formula for intrinsic curvature of a function *)
(* STEP 1 - metric tensor *)

(* Find g such that: g dY dY = δ dX dX *)

dX = {dx, dy, D[f[x, y], x] dx + D[f[x, y], y] dy};
dY = {dx, dy};

long = dX.dX // FullSimplify;


a = Coefficient[long, dx^2];
b = Coefficient[long, dx dy]/2;
c = Coefficient[long, dy^2];

g = {{a, b}, {b, c}}
gInv = Inverse[g]

short = dY.g.dY;

(* Check *)
long == short // FullSimplify



(* STEP 2 - Christoffel symbols *)

cristoffelLower = Module[{v = {x, y}},
    Table[
     D[g[[c]][[a]], v[[b]]] +
      D[g[[c]][[b]], v[[a]]] -
      D[g[[a]][[b]], v[[c]]],
     {c, 1, 2}, {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}]]/2;

(* Seconds kind - these appear to be correct*)
cristoffelHigher =
 Table[
   Plus @@ Table[
     cristoffelLower[[d]][[a]][[b]] gInv[[c]][[d]], {d, 1, 2}],
   {c, 1, 2}, {a, 1, 2}, {b, 1, 2}] // FullSimplify


(* STEP 3 - Curvature Tensors *)
reimann = Module[{v = {x, y}},
    Table[
     D[cristoffelHigher[[ρ]][[ν]][[σ]], v[[μ]]] -
      D[cristoffelHigher[[ρ]][[μ]][[σ]], v[[ν]]] +
      Plus @@ Table[
        cristoffelHigher[[ρ]][[μ]][[λ]] 
cristoffelHigher[[λ]][[ν]][[σ]], {λ, 1, 2}]
      - Plus @@ Table[
        cristoffelHigher[[ρ]][[ν]][[λ]] 
cristoffelHigher[[λ]][[μ]][[σ]], {λ, 1, 2}],
     {ρ, 1, 2}, {σ, 1, 2}, {μ, 1, 2}, {ν, 1, 
      2}]] // FullSimplify;

(* Ricci curvature, 1st position is contravariant, 3rd is covariant *)
ricci = Table[
   Plus @@ Table[
     reimann[[k]][[i]][[k]][[j]], {k, 1, 2}],
   {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];

(* Scalar curvature, both positions are covariant *)
scalar =
 Plus @@ Table[
    Plus @@ Table[
      ricci[[i]][[j]] gInv[[j]][[i]],
      {j, 1, 2}], {i, 1, 2}] // FullSimplify

(* Define a function to do the calculation *)
ScalarCurvature[fun_, xx_, yy_] := 
 scalar /. Derivative[i_, j_][f][x, y] -> D[fun, {xx, i}, {yy, j}]

GaussianCurvature[f_, x_, y_] := ScalarCurvature[f, x, y]
```

Comment: I'm getting $-\frac{4}{\left(4 x^2+4 y^2+1\right)^2}$ if I use the Gaussian curvature routine from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85834).

Comment: @J.M. Ah yes, that was a typo, I've corrected it from - to +

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to delay the evaluation of the right-hand side of ScalarCurvature:

```
 ScalarCurvature[fun_, xx_, yy_] := scalar /. Derivative[i_, j_][f][x, y] :> D[fun, {xx, i}, {yy, j}]
```

Then it works, although there is a sign difference to your formula:

```
ScalarCurvature[x^2 - y^2, x, y]
-(8/(1 + 4 x^2 + 4 y^2)^2)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.