# How to calculate the Gauss curvature of any point of function with two variables

Tags: differential-geometry

I see many methods to calculate the [Gaussian curvature](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61409/computing-gaussian-curvature/61410#61410) of [parametric surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70214/how-to-visualize-the-gaussian-curvature-of-a-3d-surface-using-color) in SE.But how to calculate the Gaussian curvature of any point of the following explicit function:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2
```

Comment: You can easily use a Gaussian curvature routine intended for parametric surfaces on a Monge patch. Using e.g. `GaussianCurvature[]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85834), try this: `GaussianCurvature[{x, y, x^2 + y^2}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @J. M. But how to eliminate the singularity of the curvature of this function:`gccolor[{x, 
   y, (x^4 - 6 x^2 y^2 + y^4)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 BesselJ[4, 
     17 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]} /. {x -> u, y -> v}, {u, -1, 1 }, {v, -1, 
  1}]`